# Tables and charts using PDFsharp

Tags: c#, charts, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I just started with a project that requires me to write to PDF file. After some googling I decided on using PDFsharp which looks simple enough, however I have a few questions regarding drawing tables and charts.

Is PDFsharp a good choice for writing PDF files that contain tables and charts? If no, can you recommend a better alternative? If yes, where could I find some good literature on the subject? A tutorial would be nice (doesn't have to be a sample project, just something I can use to familiarise myself with the library and its classes).

Can anyone tell me what MigraDoc is all about? I just took a glimpse and it seems perfect for what I need, however I would like some more information about it.

Comment: https://github.com/DavidS/MigraDoc/blob/master/PDFsharp/dev/PdfSharp.Charting.Demo/PdfSharp.Charting.Demo/ChartSamples.cs

Answer (score 31, accepted):

PDFsharp is a "low level" PDF generator, while MigraDoc is a "high level" document generator that uses PDFsharp to create PDF files, but can also create e. g. RTF.

Visit the PDFsharp/MigraDoc Foundation Website for further information:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/

Answer (score 4):

If you dont want to use MigraDoc, you can use the gfx.Drawline() and draw the table yourself.
I did it in one of my Projects.
You can do it like that:

```
        gfx.DrawLine(pen, 45, 250, 45, 703);
        gfx.DrawLine(pen, 87, 250, 87, 703);
        gfx.DrawLine(pen, 150, 250, 150, 703);
        gfx.DrawLine(pen, 291, 250, 291, 703);
        gfx.DrawLine(pen, 381, 250, 381, 703);
        gfx.DrawLine(pen, 461, 250, 461, 703);
        gfx.DrawLine(pen, 571, 250, 571, 703);
```

Or you can use a for loop to do it like that and count the postion up.